# Apache/Starman - how to implement lots of different webapps with single virtual host

Tags: apache, perl, cgi, psgi, starman

I have a lot of `CGI` web applications under `apache2`, which have complex `jQueryUI` powered interfaces and corresponding perl backend, based upon `CGI::Application` framework.

For user it looks like this:

1. //localsrv.lan/some_report_xls
2. //localsrv.lan/some_insert_db
3. //localsrv.lan/some_perl_plsql_stuff 
   etc...

Now I want to turn those apps `psgi`, which is easy, and somehow run those under `Apache->ProxyPass/Starman`

- Should I run Starman for every app using lots of ports for all of
  them?
- Should I somehow use mapping url with `Plack::App::URLMap` and
  how?
- Should I create one single app out of all those hundreds to run it with Starman
- Is there another way to do it?

Comment: I would use `Plack::App::URLMap` (or [`Plack::Builder`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Builder#URLMap-support), which uses `Plack::App::URLMap` under the hood) to mount each of your apps to a separate URL. Then you can run that single PSGI app with Starman, and requests to the different URLs will be handled by your various apps.

Comment: Thanks alot. I will follow your advice.